# What's the best way to show 'too many options with checkboxes' to user?

Tags: checkboxes, many-options

The design of my webapp requires the user to select books from 100 of books. These books are user's own books imported from another app.

[image: so many options to choose from, using checkboxes]

This step is just after the user has registered with my app. I am afraid that the user may feel inundated by so much info and might skip this step instead of judiciously selecting which books to lend.

Is there any better way to display so many (around 100) books so that the user selects the books with ease and not just hastily skips, deselect all or foolishly select all?

PS: As most of the users are suggesting for categorization, let me add that here the user has to decide whether to lend the book or not. Categorization (genre specific or have-read/want-to-read etc.) might not be very fruitful.

Comment: I think this question is worth deliberating so I added to UX SE. If this question is too much specific to my app, please let me know I'll take this down asap. Thanks.

Comment: 100 is the max number of items possible?

Comment: This doesn't fit within the way you've asked the question, but what I'd imagine is simply not asking them about all the books at once. Give them say 10 at the beginning, then have a filtered view/queue of books to look through later when they have time. That is, at least internally, think of the books as having three states: selected to lend, selected to not lend, and unreviewed.

Comment: I haven't used Facebook in awhile, but I seem to remember a similar interface for inviting many friends to an event. Seems to work well for them. :)

Comment: show a limited amount, possibly selected by date of completion, randomly, by category, by popularity, whatever suits your need, with the option of selecting or rejecting each book, and a `done for now` button at the bottom. See how http://www.senscritique.com does to engage users in rating movies and books.

Comment: @rewobs it can be more than 100 as well. Book readers might have read 300-400 books as well but the more the number of books the lesser number of people who would have read that many books.

Comment: As @njzk2 states, only show a few books. I'd lazy-load the other ones, but the 'I would love to lend' button should always be visible.

Comment: I'd recommend to check Facebook's invitations to groups or events out. List of one's friends (tens to hundreds, usually) is shown with checkboxes resembling what @dfshk suggests. But there's more: you cen edit the list multiple times (save and later add new/remove unwanted ones), there is the search option and so on. On the whole, a clever solution that is pleasure to work with.

Comment: Why do users need to decide which books to lend all in one step and so early in the process of setting up their account?

Comment: @Kevin that's a good question. Frankly there is no specific reason why we are showing this to the user so early in the process. It's just that we want users to add books to Lend so that our website has enhanced repository of books that can be lent. I'll surely think over your question and might delay this step to when the user logs in 3rd or 4th time. Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One way of making a selection task less tedious is by increasing the selection target size to the full image + text size (e.g., as in the attached mockup). This decreases the effort that goes into individual selection and can provide an appealing and easy to see overview on which books are selected. Additionally, you can distributed the 100 books over several pages.

[image]

Comment: You could expand on the second point - Users can experience cognitive overload on too many items at once. Look how amazon presents search results: You never have more than 4x3 or so at once. I would recomment big images and only 3-4 columns and then a scrolling list. So the user doesn't see too many items at once.

Answer (score 23):

I haven’t seen user testing data on this, but there’s an existing pattern that appears to work very well. In the course of on-boarding a new user profile, Netflix allows the user to select movies that he wants to watch or likes:

[image: Netflix onboard]

Notice the top row. The left item is selected, the middle item is in the hover state, and the right item is unselected. Also note that there is no particular affordance needed for selection—clicking on your choice is intuitive enough.

Answer (score 8):

I can think of three improvements:

- Adding **a** **filter**
- Adding **some order**
- Improving **scannability**

The filter is the easy one but I don't have a win-win idea for the other two, anyway I'll present some alternatives:

### If you're betting on text...

Something that could help to searchability is  **alphabetical separation**, maybe together with an **index** to each letter.

I don't really know how users will scan the books, but probably they would try to search for the image first, although I'm not sure if this will be always helpful taking into account that **not all books are** **that recognizable**, at least **in that size**.
So maybe a less loaded interface which gives more importance to the text may help them find what they want more consistently. Here's just an idea:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH6MMx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

### If you are betting on images (and less on text)

On the other hand if you could place **bigger images** (thumbnails), which could really increment the scanning efficiency and related to selection you could try something similar to the latest Google Drive Interface (image below) where you can **select by clicking anywhere on the thumbnail**.
Additionally you could place several books on each line (the number depend on the resolution) inside the same alphabetical separation.

[image]

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can always suggest some books for the user to lend and communicate that he or she can choose more later. It will successfully onboard the user and not overwhelm with too many choices.

The criteria by witch the books are suggested really depends on the purpose of the application (I particularly like Adam's idea of date last read).

Comment: It may be generally useful to have a third state "not decided yet", so I can stop and resume at any time -- this is also useful for recently added books.

Comment: Which witch did you mean? ;)

Answer (score 5):

The way you have it mocked up isn't bad. I mean, if I know my task is to go through my entire library and select loan-able books, then I expect I'll have to go through my whole library. I'd expect to see a page full of my books.

I would, though, make each item larger (showing them in 4 or even 3 columns) and make the clickable area bigger than that little checkbox, in order to make it a no-brainer to select a book. Maybe make it a button or make the entire item clickable for selection. (See Fitts' Law.)

I assume people would make their selections by browsing through everything, rather than searching/filtering for sub-sets of their books, but maybe not. (You can find out by doing some simple user research.) It seems that a Sort feature would be useful, though.

(Note: I'd use that app.)

Comment: Agreed, it looks like a pretty solid UX already. Making the whole area clickable is key. If the OP doesn't want to break it into genres, this makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to provide the user a way to apply context to their list of books in order to help them make an informed and easier decision.

Offering filters to help users sort by "date last read" or "genre" might help aid their decision making process. A user will be more likely to select all the books they haven't read in a year, or if they aren't reading crime books at the moment.

I would recommend streamlining this process for the initial onboarding step and enhancing the decision making when the user has escalated their commitment with your application. When a user finishes reading a book, writes a review, gives a book a star rating - adding an option to "add to lend list" really streamlines this feature.

Good luck, hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In case of multiple options, **categorization** always helps the user to make a decision. Netflix/Hulu do this really well and it becomes easy for you to select a title. Although, the use case is bit different here, but it more or less fits for your problem. You can categorize books by Genre, Rating, Recently read, Reading, etc.

[image]

You can use a book API to **auto categorize** books - [53 Book API's](http://www.programmableweb.com/news/53-books-apis-google-books-goodreads-and-sharedbook/2012/03/13)

Comment: Here the user has to decide whether to lend the book or not. Categorization (genre specific or have-read/want-to-read etc.) might not be very fruitful.

Comment: Categorization can help if a user has multiple books (around 100 as you said). From a UX POV, segmented information is easier to process and can lead to better participation from the user. Also, I think it can give the user more data points like which genres are most popular, etc. You can also use this data to enhance findability. Just my $0.02

Answer (score 1):

I feel as though you might be jamming too many visual cues into the same screen.

I think it should be broken out into steps:

**Step 1**

Would you like to lend any of your books at this time? (Sharing is Caring!)

Yes | No

**Step 2 - Yes**

Below are some books which you have already finished. Tap on each one which you would like to lend.

> Book | Book | Book
>
> Book | Book | Book
>
> Book | Book | Book
>
> | View all of my books! |

Lend Books | I've changed my mind, let me in!

**Step 2 - No**

That's okay! You can choose which books to lend at any time by going to X, Y, and Z!

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the newly released Apple music app. When you enter the app for the first time Apple Music asks you to select a few artists out of group and then select a few genre out of a group. I guess your requirement matches a lot with them. And believe me they have done it really well. You can try that kind of interface with some tweaks. 
Apple brings a set of bubbles in front of you to select. Tap on the circle to select.[image]

[image]

Comment: You should include more detail about the interface you're referencing, I'm guessing the majority of people looking are not familiar with what you're referencing especially in the future. Perhaps including some images

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun idea -- 3 columns, on the left there are the ones to lend on the right ones not to lend, in the center undecided.  At the start just the center is populated.  The user can click on the left or the right and the item will animate over to the new list.  The list continues off the bottom of the screen.  As the left and the right fill up they will continue off the edge.   The user can process the center part and items move up as item animate to the left and the right.

Comment: I don't think this is good practice. It makes it so that there are really long vertical lists and as soon as one moves it most likely goes way up or down the page so the user loses context of the choice

Comment: I was thinking the choice would be put on the top of the list and the others would move down.  The last picked are on top (on the left and right) and the next one to pick is on the top in the center.

Comment: That is much better but I still don't think it's optimal :P It'd also be a pain to make as a developer

Comment: You are right -- optimal would be just to get rid of the humans... what a waste of time having a UI at all.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively maybe most people are willing to lend most of their books, but not the ones they are about to read... maybe you should ask them to select books they don't want to lend right now and auto lend the rest... Under the assumption most users only have a few books they know they don't want to part with right now. Include a search filter at the top to then locate the books they don't want to lend from the whole list quickly.

I also agree with MonkeyZeus, but maybe you have somewhere else in your app where people request books they want to borrow maybe this can help identify books in the new user library that are imported that have been read, also maybe you can look up the book on a retail site and get a rating of the book and rank them higher in being displayed in the initial limited book selection.